# Remote Django application sending messages to RabbitMQ

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm starting to get familiar with the RabbitMQ lingo so I'll try my best to explain. I'll be going into a public beta test in a few weeks and this is the set up I am hoping to achieve. I would like Django to be the producer; producing messages to a remote RabbitMQ box and another Celery box listening on the RabbitMQ queue for tasks. So in total there would be three boxes. Django, RabbitMQ & Celery. So far, from the Celery docs, I have successfully been able to run Django and Celery together and Rabbit MQ on another machine. Django simply calls the task in the view:

```
add.delay(3, 3)
```

And the message is sent over to RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ sends it back to the same machine that the task was sent from (since Django and celery share the same box) and celery processes the task.

This is great for development purposes. However, having Django and Celery running on the same box isn't a great idea since both will have to compete for memory and CPU. The whole goal here is to get clients in and out of the HTTP Request cycle and have celery workers process the tasks. But the machine will slow down considerably if it is accepting HTTP requests and also processing tasks.

So I was wondering is there was a way to make this all separate from one another. Have Django send the tasks, RabbitMQ forward them, and Celery process them (Producer, Broker, Consumer).

How can I go about doing this? Really simple examples would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to deploy the code of your application on the third machine and execute there only the command that handles the tasks. You need to have the code on that machine also.

Comment: So pretty much replicate my Django box and only run the command that actually listens correct? I had a feeling that would be the way to do it.